# Bug in iOS with UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` in a Storyboard in my iOS project. I have a special TableViewCell `MessageCell` with a `UIView` inside of a specific class.

When I call `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` I get a `UITableViewCell` with only this subview tree:

```
<UITableViewCell: 0x16da5e90; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x16da5120>>
    <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x16da6210; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16da5510>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16da6280>>
    <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x16da62b0; frame = (0 -1; 15 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x16da52d0>>
```

But when I call `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`, I get this subview tree:

```
<UITableViewCell: 0x146f3a90; frame = (0 148.93; 320 54.93); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x146f2ff0>>
    <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x146f3020; frame = (0 0; 320 54.43); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x146f3e90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x146f3180>>
        <Heaven_Help.MessageView: 0x146f3f70; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; tag = 99; layer = <CALayer: 0x146f4af0>>
            <UIImageView: 0x146f4010; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x146f4090>>
            <UILabel: 0x146f40c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x146f4180>>
            <UILabel: 0x146f42d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x146f4390>>
    <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x146f31b0; frame = (0 -1; 15 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x146f3c20>>
    <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x146f5170; frame = (0 -0.5; 16 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x146c1f40>>
```

The `UIImageview` and 2 `UILabels` get added in my `MessageView` initializer.

Who can tell me what I am not getting?

As requested: my code from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    (cell.viewWithTag(99) as MessageView).setMessage(conversation[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns:

> A `UITableViewCell` object with the associated identifier or `nil` if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.

This method is typically used in a pattern like this without a storyboard:

```
MessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"messageCell"];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[MessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:…reuseIdentifier:@"messageCell"];
    // set properties that are true for EVERY cell
}

// set properties from your data model for THIS cell (usually strings and images)

return cell;
```

(With a storyboard, the method will always return a cell.)

The newer methods (like `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`) are guaranteed to return a cell, so you don't need to use this pattern any more.

The reason you're getting a `UITableViewCell` back from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is because you inserted one into the reusable-cell queue with that identifier.

Comment: I am expecting a `UITableViewCell`, but I should be getting one that contains a custom `UIView` and I don't. I don't get what is happening, but I'll use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` from now on.

Comment: If you update your question with your code from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I might be able to expand my answer to explain.

Comment: What I have always done was in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` just call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"MessageCell"]` and in my storyboard create the cell prototypes that I need. I have never needed the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` as I made the link in my storyboard. In this case I don't even have a custom `UITableViewCell`, but only a prototype that contains a custom `UIView` I need. So I don't think adding that code will help, but I have added it anyway.

Comment: Is the `MessageView` added in the storyboard, or programmatically in a different method?

Comment: @AaronBrager the way you're allocating the cell if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is not generally how tableviews from storyboards are used. OP shouldn't need to do that even without using the `forIndexPath` variant.

Comment: Aaron, it's added in the storyboard. @RodericCampbell is right. I shouldn't be getting different results from these methods.

Comment: If it's added to the storyboard, it sounds like a bug. But I just tried creating a project to reproduce it and I couldn't.

Comment: Agreed, but I think it is a bug in the code provided. @vrwim, perhaps you could supply the rest of the code if it can be put into the public domain. Maybe github. I'm pretty confident that this isn't a framework issue. I've done this setup dozens of times.

Comment: @RodericCampbell The code I'm working on is confidential and it would be easier to setup a new project and see how it is in a clean environment. I'll try to set up one tonight.

Comment: Looking forward to it

Comment: I am currently using the forIndexPath one and it seems to work, so I guess it's just a weird thing in the API. imho, these 2 methods should return the same thing...

Comment: @RodericCampbell I can't reproduce it, I'll have to see what I did and try to remove things bit by bit. I'll let you know if I can find something.